# Qt Transform matrix

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, qt-quick

I need to manipulate QML items through QMatrix4x4, in order to apply some perspective transformations. Basically, I defined the class Transform to use an object QMatrix4x4 as argument for the transform field of the QML Item

```
class Transform : public QQuickTransform{
 Q_OBJECT

 Q_PROPERTY(QMatrix4x4 matrix READ matrix WRITE setMatrix NOTIFY matrixChanged)

 public:
 explicit Transform(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

 QMatrix4x4 matrix() const;
 void setMatrix(QMatrix4x4 matrix);

 virtual void applyTo(QMatrix4x4 *matrix) const;

 signals:
         void matrixChanged();

 private:
         QMatrix4x4 m_matrix;

};
```

where

```
void Transform::applyTo(QMatrix4x4 *matrix) const {
      *matrix *= m_matrix;
       matrix->optimize();
}
```

However, it seems that QML doesn't "define" the perspective matrix in the classical way. I've focused my tests mainly on the rotations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).
Let's say I have a QML Item in x:200, y:200 and I apply the transform

```
transform: [Transform{matrix:mytra},Rotation {  axis { x: 1; y: 0; z: 0 } angle: 90 } ]
```

where mytra is the identity matrix. The method applyTo() receives the (rotation) matrix

```
     1    -0.195312         0       200         
     0    -0.195312         0       200         
     0            0         1         0         
     0 -0.000976562         0         1
```

but the "classical" one should be

```
     1    0         0       200         
     0    0        -1       200         
     0    1         0         0         
     0    0         0         1
```

I don't understand where this matrix comes from and how to adapt my matrix to qt.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 20):

The math Qt is performing is correct, but the frame of reference that Qt is using doesn't match up with what you are thinking.

Matrix Math:

[image]

So the components you are seeing in the math are adding shear in the x and y directions of image.

But the rotation that Qt does is about one of those axis.  So if you want to do a standard 2D rotation, without shearing, you need to either not specify an axis or you specify the z axis.

> The axis to rotate around. For simple (2D) rotation around a point, you do not need to specify an axis, as the default axis is the z axis `(axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 })`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rotation.html

The rotation about the y axis looks like this:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks...however I don't understand what's the point of the 4x4 matrix. Is it to manage the z coordinate?

Comment: Yes.  A 3x3 matrix can keep track of rotations in the x and y and the translations (pos) and scale in the x and y.  A 4x4 matrix can keep track of x, y, and z rotations, scale, and translation (aka pos, or position).  Robotics makes use of the 4x4 matricies a lot. 3D rendering on graphics cards make use of 4x4 matricies, too.  If you look into OpenGL, it uses it all over the place.

Comment: How do we translate a QML Rectangle along the Z axis?