# Zoom to rectangle over Image javascript/QML

Tags: javascript, image, qml

I have a div of fixed size and an `Image` inside it. I create a `Rectangle` over the `Image` and I want to zoom into that `Rectangle`.

In the following code:
`highlightItem` is the `Rectangle` inside the `Image` and it contains `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. `output` is the `Image` and it contains `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

What I tried to do is to "move" the `Image`to the center of the `Rectangle` and then scale the `Image`.

```
var parentMiddleX = output.x + output.width/2;
var parentMiddleY = output.y + output.height/2;

var highlightMiddleX = highlightItem.x + highlightItem.width/2;
var highlightMiddleY = highlightItem.y + highlightItem.height/2;

output.x = (parentMiddleX - highlightMiddleX); 
output.y = (parentMiddleY - highlightMiddleY);

output.scale = Math.sqrt((output.width*output.height)/(highlightItem.width*highlightItem.height));
```

Basically I want to do something similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapRect%28android.graphics.RectF%29), but in QML.

Comment: Transformations can be applied via [Matrix4x4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-matrix4x4.html) which is a [basic type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-matrix4x4.html). Look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628465/qml-using-matrix4x4-transform) and related comments/answers.

Comment: Can you point me to what matrix manipulation might give me the result I need? It seems that I can set the width, height, x and y without using a matrix

Comment: Ok, I've re-read your question and you can achieve what you want by simply setting the `Image` to the propose position. The thing is, you should check how [`fillMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#fillMode-prop) is set since it can block your code. Posting a minimum working example could help a lot to check the current state of the code.