# How do we translate a QML Rectangle on the Z axis, not just X and Y?

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, transform

Is it possible to translate a QML Rectangle on the Z axis similar to how we can do in HTML with CSS `transform:translateZ()` and `transform:translate3d()`?

Applying `transform: Translate {x: 0; y: 0; z: 100}` on a Rectangle throws an error that the z property isn't defined.

I am able to apply `transform: Rotation{}` to a Rectangle with a z-axis rotation and it looks 3D. I was hoping I could translate things in 3D as well.

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: I tried setting a Matrix4x4 like this:

```
        transform: Matrix4x4 {
            matrix: Qt.matrix4x4(
                1,0,0,0,
                0,1,0,0,
                0,0,1,10,
                0,0,0,1
            )
        }
```

I set the number `10` where I believe the Z translation is, but the Rectangle just disappears instead of getting a little closer to the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Applying transform: `Translate {x: 0; y: 0; z: 100}` on a [`Rectangle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) throws an error as expected as `Translate` only has only `x` and `y` properties (See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-translate.html).

The `Transform` does not correspond with how you are trying to use it as `z` is not the position along the z-axis. `z` is the "stacking order" which is used to control which items are drawn on top or below other items (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop).

If you wanted to let your `Rectangle` appear "a little closer to the camera", `Scale` seems like a possible `Transform` to use (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-scale.html) or just use the item's `scale` property (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#scale-prop).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919378/qt-transform-matrix) might also be helpful to you as someone else had a similar question. It illustrates how you can rotate along different axis.  For example, You could do something like: `transform: Rotation { origin.x: 50; origin.y: 55; axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 60}`.

Note though that it is not possible to actually translate a QML [`Rectangle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) along the "z-axis".  So if your goal is to create a 3D scene in QML, two possible options are [Qt Canvas3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-index.html) or the [Qt3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-qmlmodule.html) module. If you want to use three.js check out this [post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/06/05/porting-three-js-code-to-canvas3d/)

Comment: Using scale for this is a hack. I want to rotate things and move them around in 3D space, similar to this HTML5 example: http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_periodictable Click on "SPHERE" and/or rotate the scene to see that it's in 3D.

Comment: You could do something like:  'transform: Rotation { origin.x: 50; origin.y: 55; axis { x: 1; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 60}'.  But I don't think that is what you are looking for based on the example you linked to.  If you are wanting to use three.js check out [Qt Canvas 3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-index.html) and this post https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/06/05/porting-three-js-code-to-canvas3d/

Comment: If you want to create a 3D scene in QML, two options are [Qt Canvas3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-index.html) or the [Qt3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-qmlmodule.html) module

Comment: Can I use a Rectangle inside of Qt3D (I think Canvas 3D is out of the picture. I still want the benefit of Item, Rectangle, etc, but simply want to manipulate them in 3D space like we can do with HTML DOM and CSS transforms.

Comment: Seems like QML Transform type should support 3D to at least be on the same level as HTML in that regard.

Comment: No, AFAIK you can't use |Rectangle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) in Qt3D.  But Qt 3D rendering can be combined with Qt Quick 2D elements. Check out [this](http://www.kdab.com/overview-qt3d-2-0-part-2/) (see the bit on "Qt Quick 2 Integration"). and see the http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-planets-qml-example.html for an example

Comment: Looks like the web is winning! We can mix WebGL with DOM by matching both coordinate spaces together as in this example: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/ (which would be equivalent to mixing Rectangles, etc, with a Qt3D scene if/when they add the last Z axis for transforms).